# How to create a shortcut to PC Settings?

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts

I need a shortcut (typical shortcut file, script, special exe, doesn't matter) for PC Settings in Windows 8.

I see that PC Settings is an executable named SystemSettings.exe, found in C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel.

However, creating a shortcut to it doesn't work. The same if I try to run this executable from the Command Prompt, for example.

Any ideas on how to create such a shortcut?

Comment: If you know how to do it in Windows 7, you can just apply that to the Desktop "app"

Comment: For the start screen, though, I can't help...

Comment: There is no PC Settings in Windows 7. PC Settings is the new Control Panel in Windows 8, with settings related to the new interface, among other things.

Comment: Open the charms (on the right) -> go to settings -> change PC settings (on the bottom of the Settings charm).

Comment: You mean the thing you get when you click 'PC Settings' in the 'Charm Bar'? It's already there, isn't it? Why do you need more?

Comment: Or... a stupid way of doing it: Go to Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety -> User Accounts. There click on "Make changes to my account in PC Settings".

Comment: I need a shortcut PC Settings. Something you can run on the Desktop, or from the command line to launch it.

Comment: Since this seems to be a Metro App, you can't make a desktop shortcut (from what I have read, someone might find a shortcut) - your best bet is to get a program like Start8, which can launch metro apps, but it also adds a start button - I recommend keeping the metro screen.

Comment: I know that officialy you can't do that but... as with everything else related to technology, there must be a way to hack around this.

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Comment: Because such a shortcut would be useful to many users. Opening PC Settings requires just too many clicks and steps. It should be as easy as opening Control Panel. But it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used the approach recommended by @Ryan. However, I did create a shorter script, that is less error prone (sort of):

```
Send("#i")
Sleep (100)
Send("{END}")
Sleep (50)
Send("{ENTER}")
```

If you don't want to create the script yourself, you can download the final result from an article I published on the topic. It is a small executable with a nice icon, etc.

[Download a Desktop Shortcut to PC Settings, for Windows 8](http://www.7tutorials.com/download-desktop-shortcut-pc-settings-windows-8)

Appreciate everyone's input on the topic. It was definitely useful.

Answer (score 4):

If you are open to hacks, then I've got one for you. I'm using AutoHotKey to do it. I have a 1920x1080 screen, so if your resolution is different, the mouse click command will have to be different. Here's the script, using Win+S as the shortcut to fire this:

```
#s::
Send #i
Sleep 1000
Click 1756,1050
Return
```

Any time I hit Win+S, it will send the Win+I command, wait for it to pop open, then click on "Change PC Settings." I didn't spend too much time playing with the sleep time, but feel free to adjust that down if your computer is faster than mine.

EDIT:

A screen resolution independent script is provided below:

```
#s::
Send #i
Sleep 1000
Send {Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Down}{Enter}
Return
```

Answer (score 2):

The Settings charm has a keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Windows logo key</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

If that's the one you are looking for, you can either just use this keyboard shortcut instead
of a desktop shortcut, or use a macro product such as [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create a compiled script
that can be called via a desktop shortcut and that will issue this combination of keys.

Even if that's not the solution, a AutoHotkey script might be able to reproduce all the mouse actions that one uses to call up PC Settings on Windows 8 (however, not having Windows 8, I cannot verify).

Comment: That keyboard combination takes you to the Settings charm, not PC Settings. But I am looking into some custom scripting right now, based on keyboard shortcuts and key presses to make it work every time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that script is what you are looking for:

```
explorer.exe shell:::{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

Microsoft published a list of all Canonical Names of Control Panel Items here:
[Canonical Names of Control Panel Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330741%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: On my computer that opens up some "All Tasks" menu on the desktop rather than the "Change PC Settings" pane in Metro

Comment: This doesn't work as a shortcut for PC Settings.