# How to pin the PC Settings App to Windows 8 Start Screen

Tags: windows-8

How can I add PC Settings as a Tile to Start Screen? Each time i need to access Settings, i need to search for a related task and i find it annoying. Is there a way to pin the Settings App (Modern UI one) to the Start Screen?

Note: I'm not talking about Control Panel. I'm talking about this:

[image]

And no, its not available by default on the Start screen. At least I do not remember unpinning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (I don't even think that Windows Store apps can do this the way that they can pin folders). The fastest way to get to settings is to use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> and click `Change PC Settings` in the bottom right corner.

**Edit:** a way to do this completely without the mouse:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! That was something I'd not noticed previously. But are you sure about not being able to pin? Cos.. its still quite tedious.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish I added another way to do it, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This link worked for me: http://www.7tutorials.com/download-desktop-shortcut-pc-settings-windows-8 
After i downloaded the executable, i created a shortcut in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs which helped me pin a Settings tile on my Start Screen

Answer (score 1):

Update to Windows 8.1 from the Windows Store, and the PC settings app appears in the All Apps list. You can pin it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pin it. If you see my response to a question about [keyboard shortcuts to PC Settings](https://superuser.com/questions/478283/how-to-create-a-shortcut-to-pc-settings/479995#479995), you can snag the AutoHotKey script I wrote to do it.